# Showing that this function is surjective

Tags: functions

I'm working through a question that asks whether a function is surjective and/or 1-1.

The question is framed as follows.

> Let $S$ be an arbitrary subset of the natural numbers of size 5. Let $P(S)$ be the power set of $S.$
>
> There is a function $f : P(S) \to N$ defined by $f(T) = \sum_{x \in T} x \, \operatorname{(mod} 31)$ for $T \in P(S).$
>
> Determine if $f$ is surjective and/or 1-1

So far, I have determined the following.

- $P(S)$ contains $2^5 = 32$ elements.
- $|f(S)| = 31$

So, the function cannot be 1-1 due to there being 32 elements mapping to 31 results.

I understand that the function is surjective, but I'm not really sure how you would show that this is the case in this question.

Comment: Is your spell-checker messing you around? Anyway I suspect there are choices of $S$ for which the function is not surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is correct. You can employ a similar argument to prove surjectivity. Indeed, $P(S)$ has 32 elements. $\mathbb N$ on the other hand, is infinite. Hence, there are 32 elements mapping to an infinite set. Certainly, they cannot map to everything. More formally: $|im(f)| \leq |P(S)| = 32 < \infty$.